# Trigger an alert if selector is clicked

Tags: jquery, selector

I've just gotten back into coding after a long while. I'm creating a page that uses a panorama programme that works really well. There are hotspots on the screen and the programme allows me to add selectors to the different hotspots. How can I trigger an alert (or something else later) when one of the hotspots is clicked? In this case #do_something.

```
   <style>
#mypanorama {
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
}
</style>
<!-- /end main style -->
</head>
<body>

<div id="mypanorama"></div>

<script src="assets/js/lib/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/lib/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/lib/jquery.ipanorama.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
```

Jquery

```
$("#mypanorama").ipanorama({
  "theme": "ipnrm-theme-dark",
  "autoLoad": false,
  "autoRotate": false,
  "autoRotateSpeed": 0.001,
  "autoRotateInactivityDelay": 3000,
  "mouseWheelPreventDefault": true,
  "mouseWheelRotate": false,
  "mouseWheelRotateCoef": 0.2,
  "mouseWheelZoom": true,
  "mouseWheelZoomCoef": 0.05,
  "hoverGrab": false,
  "hoverGrabYawCoef": 20,
  "hoverGrabPitchCoef": 20,
  "grab": true,
  "grabCoef": 0.1,
  "pinchZoom": true,
  "pinchZoomCoef": 0.1,
  "showControlsOnHover": false,
  "showSceneThumbsCtrl": false,
  "showSceneMenuCtrl": false,
  "showSceneNextPrevCtrl": true,
  "showShareCtrl": false,
  "showZoomCtrl": true,
  "showFullscreenCtrl": true,
  "showAutoRotateCtrl": false,
  "sceneThumbsVertical": true,
  "sceneThumbsStatic": false,
  "title": true,
  "compass": false,
  "keyboardNav": false,
  "keyboardZoom": false,
  "sceneNextPrevLoop": false,
  "popover": true,
  "popoverPlacement": "top",
  "hotSpotBelowPopover": true,
  "popoverShowTrigger": "hover",
  "popoverHideTrigger": "leave",
  "mobile": false,
  "sceneId": "scene1",
  "sceneFadeDuration": 3000,
  "sceneBackgroundLoad": false,
  "scenes": {
    "scene1": {
      "type": "sphere",
      "cubeTextureCount": "single",
      "sphereWidthSegments": 100,
      "sphereHeightSegments": 40,
      "image": "upload/my_image.jpg",
      "saveCamera": true,
      "title": "corridor",
      "titleHtml": false,
      "titleSelector": null,
      "hotSpots": [
        {
          "title": "enter",
          "yaw": 107.13427,
          "pitch": -4.22567,
          "imageUrl": "",
          "imageWidth": null,
          "imageHeight": null,
          "link": null,
          "linkNewWindow": false,
          "popoverHtml": true,
          "popoverContent": null,
          "popoverSelector": "#do_something",
          "popoverLazyload": true,
          "popoverShow": false
        }
      ]
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Please include a [mcve] to your question.  Otherwise it may be very hard to help you. For example, what does the HTML look like?

Comment: This is basic jQuery: `$("selector").click(function() {alert("clicked");})`

Comment: Well yes, that's what I thought but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Try adding a `$(document).ready()` wrap around your panorama init.